# How to "compile" a module?

Tags: webpack

I don't know exactly how to phrase this question so I will do it with an example. (Feel free to edit the question title to something more appropriate)

Consider the following example:

```js
    import foo from 'foo'
    import bar from 'bar'

    import DATA from './data.json'

    const MY_DATA = foo.process(DATA).filter(bar.isBar)

    export default class {
        get data() {
            return MY_DATA
        }

        propA = true

        methodB() {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Is it possible import this module having **only this class (and the content of `MY_DATA`)** bundled by Webpack? That is, somehow explicit that I don't want to include 'foo', 'bar' nor './data.json' in this chunk.

Back in the day I would do it using the ignore plugin, but I'm not sure if that still the only option for Webpack 4 since ignoring a module during the whole build isn't always the desirable effect.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `externals` is what you're searching for.
From the [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals):

> Prevent bundling of certain imported packages and instead retrieve
>   these external dependencies at runtime.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',

    DATA: './data.json'
  }
};
```

This requires you to add your externalized scripts manually to your HTML document.